# SectionInformation.AllowOverride vs SectionInformation.InheritInChildApplications

Tags: .net

AllowOverride says:

```
Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the associated configuration section can be overridden by lower-level configuration files.
```

InheritInChildApplications says:

```
Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the settings that are specified in the associated configuration section are inherited by applications that reside in a subdirectory of the relevant application.
```

Is this a settings vs section deal or what is the difference?